# Why is it necessary for the domain to be bounded for this banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

I have an elementary question regarding this definition, from [the site of the University of Bath, UK](https://people.bath.ac.uk/mw2319/ma40203/section-6.html):

Theorem 2.18. $C^k(\Omega)$ is Banach. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded open set and let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $C^k(\bar{\Omega})$ is a Banach space with the norm

\begin{equation*}
{||f||}_{C^k(\Omega)} = \sum_{|\alpha| \le k} \sup_\Omega {|\partial^\alpha f|}\text{,}
\end{equation*}

where here the sum is over all multiindices $\alpha$ with order $\leq k.$

Why is it important to consider $\Omega$ to be a **bounded** set? (In case of euclidean space, maybe boundedness would help us when considering the support of a function, but I am finding it difficult to understand the importance of boundedness, in general.)

Comment: It is important for the $\sup$ to be finite.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! Could you elaborate a bit more? I thought that the finiteness of the sup depends on the function rather than the domain. Is there some relation that I'm missing?

Comment: The theorem used here is that if a real-valued function is continuous on a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^N$ (like $\bar\Omega$ here) then its sup on that subset is attained hence finite.

Comment: To elaborate,  $f(x)=x$ is $C^\infty$,   but if you let the domain be unbounded, say all of $\mathbb{R}$,   then the $sup(f)=\infty$.   On any bounded set, though you are good